# Unable to execute EXE remotely using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

There is an exe file on backup server “Backupsrv”  `C:\Program files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\admincmd\bpdbjobs.exe`.

When I run this exe on “Backupsrv” using PowerShell it is giving some output on console

```
& "C:\Program Files\Veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpdbjobs.exe" -all_columns
```

Now I tried to run this exe from an application server remotely using `Invoke-Command` as below.

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "backupsrv" -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
    & "C:\Program Files\Veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpdbjobs.exe" -all_columns
}
```

No result When executed remotely.

[image]

The exe is being executed but not giving any result.

Comment: The command may be writing to the console directly, rather than standard output. To check that, try redirecting the output to a file. (The `bpdbjobs` manpage suggests that you can write the output directly using `-file`; see if that produces anything to verify the command really is running.)

Comment: Yes, `Out-File` will redirect what PowerShell sees as the output; using `bpdbjobs.exe -all_columns -file c:\temp\result.txt` tells `bpdbjobs.exe` itself to write to that file.

Comment: Also try: $result=Invoke-Command -ComputerName "backupsrv" -Credential $cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock{$Output = & "C:\Program Files\Veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpdbjobs.exe" -all_columns; return $Output}

Comment: You could also try creating and entering a PSSession, and invoking the command in that session directly, rather than using `Invoke-Command` to remote execute.

Comment: $result=Invoke-Command -ComputerName "backupsrv" -Credential $cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock{$Output = & "<C:\Program Files\Veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd\bpdbjobs.exe>" -most_columns ; return $Output}     I was able to get the output when i use this command... Seems the problem is with switch.. when i execute "dpdbjobs.exe -all_columns" its not returning any output. Is there any other way to troubleshoot the reason. When i execute this command on local server receiving proper output. Thanks all for the support.